# Qt: is there any memory leak in the following code?

Tags: qt

As a newcomer to Qt, I am just wandering whether the following simple code would have any memory leak.

```
#include <QtGui>
int main(int argc, char * argv[])
{
    QApplication app(argc, argv);
    QMainWindow *win = new QMainWindow();
    win->show();
    return app.exec();
}
```

This code runs OK. But the `QMainwindow` is being created in the heap while there seems no suitable place to insert statement to `delete` it from the heap. Although the program heap space seems would be released after the program terminates. I wander whether this is a good style in writing Qt program.

I saw this style of Qt programming in some Qt examples. So I raise the question here for suggestions.

Thanks for any idea.

Comment: once you return from main, you're terminating the program...

Comment: When the program terminates, I think all the heap objects would be released. But I wander why I could not delete the QMainWindow heap object before the program terminates. Why some Qt examples use this style of coding. Perhaps this is a minor mistake.

Comment: There is no mistake in Qt style. It's your misundersood of Qt objects memory managnent. In your case it is OK to create QMainWindow on stack. But in all other cases it's prefferable to create QObjects/QWidgets in heap.

Comment: @Dmitry Sazonov In fact, I ask this question as I saw some Qt examples written in this style. I know that I could create the `QMainWindow` in stack instead of heap. I am just wander why the Qt examples are written in that way and not sure whether the Qt objects memory management would handle the heap properly for us.

Comment: Just to follow same code style

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Qt very much depends on object/widget hierarchies for resource cleanup. Child widgets are child objects of their parent widgets, so when the parent gets deleted, the children are cleaned up as well.

I therefore recommend you ensure that the QMainWindow is deleted properly, so when you add child widgets, you can know that all their resources are destroyed properly at program shutdown.

To do so, either allocate the main window on the stack in `main()`:

```
QMainWindow win;
win.show();
```

Or use one of the various smart pointer classes to ensure cleanup:

```
QScopedPointer<QMainWindow> win = new QMainWindow;
win->show();
```

Answer (score 1):

This is not the kind of memory leak you need to worry too much about, but you can fix it very simply by making the `QMainWindow` a child of `QApplication`:

```
    QMainWindow *win = new QMainWindow(&app);
```

`QObjects` such as `QApplication` delete all child objects when they are deleted. So in this case, the `QApplication` would delete the `QMainWindow` when `app` goes out of scope.

Comment: [`QMainWindow` constructor](https://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qtwidgets/qmainwindow.html#QMainWindow) wants a `QWidget` type as the parent, so that wouldn't work. `QWidget` based objects can only have `QWidget` based objects as parents.

Comment: Then say `win->QObject::setParent(&app);` instead.

Comment: Links `QMainWindow` to a `QObject` seems also a possible solution.

Comment: @StefanMajewsky Won't work. [See the source](https://qt.gitorious.org/qt/qt/source/fd529383c4491580db344fb3d8035bd0ad3cb5e0:src/corelib/kernel/qobject.cpp#L1963). `Q_ASSERT(!d->isWidget);`.

Answer (score 0):

You can make the display a widget, and put it onto the main window. That would be much more flexible and would make you able to control the main window's bloating. But this is more about design than about Qt itself...

Comment: `QMainWindow` is already inherited from `QWidget`. I could put other `QWidget` into the `QMainWindow`. But I just wander the possible memory leak in this style of programming.